# how this instance of Array works?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This code is generating the content of callback function **13** times, but my question is how **...new** rest operator is working from a new instance of an array?

```
{
  [...new Array(12)]
  .map(
      () => `Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.
                  Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.
                  Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.
                  Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.`
    )
    .join("\n")
}
```

Comment: `new Array(12)` creates an array with 12 empty slots. Spreading that into another array seems to then convert the items into `undefined`. `map` won't iterate over empty slots, but it does with undefined values.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of an `array` is defined as: ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array)):

```
new Array(element0, element1, /* … ,*/ elementN)
new Array(arrayLength)
```

That said, you can create an `Array` of a specified length with `new Array(n)`, or in your example with 12 elements. This results in an array of 12 items:

> this implies an array of arrayLength empty slots, not slots with actual undefined values ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array))

Only if you access one item with `array[index]`, the item gets `undefined`.

As a spread operator basically gets all elements of the array, `[... new Array(12)]` will return in an array of 12x `undefined`.

Mapping over it, to see what's really in each item:

```
[...new Array(12)].map((value, index) => ({value,index}))
```

results in

```json
[{value: undefined, "index":0},{value: undefined, "index":1},{value: undefined, "index":2},{value: undefined, "index":3},{value: undefined, "index":4},{value: undefined, "index":5},{value: undefined, "index":6},{value: undefined, "index":7},{value: undefined, "index":8},{value: undefined, "index":9},{value: undefined, "index":10},{value: undefined, "index":11}]
```

To came back to your example; it doesn't matter, if you've got an empty param function in `map`, important is, what get's returned. If you don't need the param (as in your example), discard it.

Additionally, it doesn't get called 13 times. It's actually 12; the length of the created array.

Comment: Thanks felix, that's mean we have 12 undefined items that filled with map callback function value in each specific iteration.